# Which programming language for multilingual Bible app?

Tags: programming-languages

I was wondering, in order to make a user-friendly web-based program for reading the Bible in several foreign languages, which programming language would be best to use?

Some criteria:

-Bible would be able to be read linearly. So one verse will be in English, but the line underneath the verse would be the same verse but in a different language like Chinese. So I think I would need to be able to create different databases for each language.

-Would like to make words clickable for definitions, so would need some dictionary database and be able to display several boxes at once on the program interface (one box will be just the bible text, another box would be the dictionary definitions).

- Would like users to be able to drag the boxes or toggle the boxes on and off, to customize the way they want to display the features of the program.

-Would like to be able to let users create a username and password and login to their personal accounts which will save their settings and any notes they make.

I am familiar with coding but I am no expert, if you could please help me out and let me know which programming language (and maybe which functions in that programming language?) would be best to help me create what I mentioned above. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would recommend finding a mature program that already does something similar and improving that. cf. http://wiki.c2.com/?TheZenOfProgramming

In particular, how would you be improving on, for example, [bibleWebApp](http://biblewebapp.com)? Or [The Sword Project](http://www.crosswire.org/applications/)? Or [And Bible](https://andbible.github.io/)? Or [BibleTime](http://bibletime.info/)?

There is certainly an argument for writing code in order to learn, but if that is not what you are doing, the world will be better off if you apply your energy to improving existing code and not to reinventing the wheel.

Given that, the answer to your question is:

- use the programming language that the mature program uses; or
- use whatever programming language you want to learn about

Comment: Wow, thanks! I didn't know that open source bibles were available like that! I have been looking at all of them. I see one uses Python, one uses Java. However, I would like to make the program web-based so that I can easily edit it. I think bibleWebApp would be my best starting point. I see that it uses HTML and Javascript. The only thing I can't figure out is that if I want to use the bible libraries provided by The Sword Project, the bibles seem to be written in C++, so how can I get my web-based program to access the C++ files and turn them into readable text that displays in a web browser?